# css border-collapse not applying

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I'm having trouble getting my inner table to not show the borders.

in the html below, it is the table `<table class="billing_history" id="billing_history0" >`.  I want the table to ultimately have only top and bottom borders for the rows, but I couldn't get that to work.  In fact, I couldn't seem to get a lot of the border properties to apply to the table.  In particular, I tried setting `border-collapse: collapse;` in the css but that didn't apply to the inner table.  However, if I set the style tag in the table itself (i.e. `style="border-collapse: collapse;"`) it DOES work.  So for some reason, the `border-collapse: collapse;` in the css isn't applying to the inner table, while other properties (i.e. `font-size: 11px;`) ARE being applied.

Anyone have any ideas?  The HTML and CSS are below...

I appreciate any suggestions you guys might have!

html:

```
<table id="bill-list">
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th>Service Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Patient Name</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Service Description</th>
            <th>COMMENTS</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
            <tr id="bill0" class="no-bills" onclick="showBillDetails(0); setFocusOnFirstInputField(0);">
                    <td class="no-bills">2009-03-03&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="no-bills">09:45:00&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="no-bills">bob</td>
                    <td class="no-bills">asdfasdf</td>
                    <td class="no-bills">asdfasdf</td>
                    <td class="no-bills">asdfasdf</td>
                    <td class="no-bills">blahblah</td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="bill">
                <td id="bill_details0" style="display:;" colspan=7> 
                    <span onclick="addBillingItem(0)" style="color:blue;">Add Item</span>           
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Billing Code</td>
                                <td>Amount</td>
                                <td>Units</td>
                                <td>Dx Code</td>
                                <td>Dx Description</td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td>SLI Code</td>
                            </tr>
                        <thead>
                        <tbody id="billing_items0">
                                <tr id="billing_item0_0">
                                    <td onclick="deleteBillingItem(0, 0)" style="color:blue;">X</td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" size="6" name="bill_code0[]" onkeydown="if (isMoveBetweenBills(event)) {    moveBetweenBills(event, 0); }" /> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" size="6" name="amount0[]" onkeydown="if (isMoveBetweenBills(event)) {   moveBetweenBills(event, 0); }" /> </td>

                                    <td> <input type="text" size="3" name="units0[]" onkeydown="if (isMoveBetweenBills(event)) {    moveBetweenBills(event, 0); }" /> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" size="6" name="dx_code0[]" onkeydown="if (isMoveBetweenBills(event)) {  moveBetweenBills(event, 0); }" /> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" size="12" name="dx_desc0[]" onkeydown="if (isMoveBetweenBills(event)) { moveBetweenBills(event, 0); }" /> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" size="6" name="total0[]" onkeydown="if (isTabKey(event) && checkIfLastBillingItem(0, 0)) {  addBillingItem(0); } else if (isEnterKey(event)) {  submitBill(0); } return true;" /> </td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" size="6" name="sli_code0[]" /> </td>

                                </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <span id="more_details_button0" onclick="showMoreDetails(0, 34601, ); " style="color:blue;">more</span>
                    <table class="more_details">
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <table class="billing_history" id="billing_history0" >
                                <tbody><tr><td>1234</td><td>2012-01-01</td><td>09:00:00</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td><td>n/a</td></tr><tr><td>1234</td><td>0.00</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>----</td><td>0.00</td></tr><tr><td>1234</td><td>0.00</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>blah blah</td><td>0.00</td></tr></tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <table id="appointment_notes0" >
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```css
.search_details
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#bill-list
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    /*margin: 45px;*/
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#bill-list th
{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe;
    border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
}
#bill-list td
{
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e8edff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#bill-list tr:hover td
{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: #339;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#bill-list #bill td
{
    background: white;
}

#bill-list .no-bills
{
    background: #e8edff;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#bill-list tr:hover .no-bills
{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#bill-list #bill .more_details tr td
{
    background: #e8edff;
    border: none;
}

#bill-list #bill .billing_history tr td
{
    background: red;
    border: none;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;

    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 1px;

    text-decoration:none;
    border-style:none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: i don't see any borders here. in your html you didn't include </tbody></table> by typo or you don't have them in your page? http://jsfiddle.net/DDkMX/

Comment: oops sorry, I forgot them in the copy/paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting border collapse on

```
#bill-list #bill table
```

border-collapse only applies to the table, not the td, according to [mozilla doco](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse)

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks Dan!  also, didn't really know much about mozilla doco, I might have to look more into that.
cheers

Comment: No probs, glad it helped. Mozilla doco is **the bomb** - the reference doco is top notch, and the guides are usually pretty good to.